# docker image syntax error

Tags: image, containers, dockerfile, docker-image

When I run docker command on my image, it errors out. Any ideas on what should I include in my Dockerfile for CMD? Currently, I have java -jar xxxx.jar in it.

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY ./target/hola-docker-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar D:/docker-built-test
WORKDIR -p D:/docker-built-test
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "hola-docker-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

My command `docker build -t hello-manual-build1 .`

click here [Created Docker Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMjz.png)

[When am trying to create a container using the new image then facing an error don't know how to resolve please help me to move forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTMMZ.png)

Thanks

Comment: Why the strange paths inside the container? Also what is the `-p` after `WORKDIR`? I bet your “working directory” is getting set to `-p`.

Comment: By using the -p flag we’re telling docker to expose the container’s port 8080 (on the right of the colon) on the host’s port 8000 (on the left, our machine). We can access from our machine to localhost:8000

Comment: That flag is a command line flag to the for the `docker run` command. It has no place after the WORKDIR directive. I think it’s actually causing your container to have the work dir set to “-p” instead of what you want. Remove it.